# The function in the child class is not called

Tags: python, class, oop, pyqt5, pyserial

1. There is a class that is responsible for the Interface (Ui MainWindow). It has a method -setup- and its attributes.
2. There is a class named JustomMainWindow, which inherits the method of the interface class and in it I already prescribe functions for processing attributes. And everything works in the current class
3. Then there is the problematic Worker 1 class, which is inherited from JustomMainWindow. From the JustomMainWindow class, I want to call the serialSend() **(mainWindow.serialSend([2, controlXY]))** function in Worker1 and pass a parameter to this function with the ControlXY argument. But here's the problem, the function is not being worked out.

Code:

```
from GoodNessMain import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMenuBar, QAction, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import cv2
import math


class CustomMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.Worker = Worker1()
        self.Worker.start()

        self.Worker.ImageUpdate.connect(self.ImageUpdateSlot)


        # ------------------------- SerialPorl ------------------------- #

        self.serial = QSerialPort()
        self.serial.setBaudRate(115200)
        self.serial.readyRead.connect(self.onRead)
        portList = []
        ports = QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()
        for port in ports:
            portList.append(port.portName())
        self.comL.addItems(portList)
        for i, port in enumerate(portList):
            comL = self.menuPortList.addAction(str(port))
            comL.triggered.connect(self.onOpen)
            if i >= 2:
                break
        self.actionOpenPort.triggered.connect(self.onOpen)
        self.actionClosePort.triggered.connect(self.onClose)
        self.actionReset.triggered.connect(self.onReset)

        # ------------------------- SerialPorl ------------------------- #

        self.speedSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.dSpeed)
        self.servoSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.dServo)
        self.ledC.stateChanged.connect(self.ledControl)
        self.QR_Forward.clicked.connect(self.dFORWARD)
        self.QR_Stop.clicked.connect(self.dSTOP)
        self.QR_Back.clicked.connect(self.dBACKWARD)

    def onReset(self):
        portlist = []
        ports = QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()
        for port in ports:
            portlist.append(port.portName())
        self.comL.clear()
        self.comL.addItems(portlist)
        self.menuPortList.clear()
        for i, port in enumerate(portlist):
            comL = self.menuPortList.addAction(str(port))
            comL.triggered.connect(self.onOpen)
            if i >= 2:
                break
    def onOpen(self):
        self.serial.setPortName(self.comL.currentText())
        self.serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)
    def onClose(self):
        self.serial.close()
    def onRead(self):
        if not self.serial.canReadLine():
            return
        rx = self.serial.readLine()
        rxs = str(rx, 'utf-8').strip()
        data = rxs.split(',')
        if data[0] == '0':
            self.temperaturL01.display(data[1])
            self.temperaturL02.display(data[2])
    def serialSend(self, data):
        txs = ""
        for val in data:
            txs += str(val)
            txs += ','
        txs = txs[:-1]
        txs += ';'
        self.serial.write(txs.encode())
    def ledControl(self, val):
        if val == 2: val = 1;
        self.serialSend([0, val])
    def dSpeed(self, val):
        self.serialSend([1, self.speedSlider.value()])
    def dServo(self, val):
        self.serialSend([2, self.servoSlider.value()])


    def dFORWARD(self, val):
        self.serialSend([3, int(val)])

    def dSTOP(self, val):
        self.serialSend([4, int(val)])
    def dBACKWARD(self, val):
        self.serialSend([5, int(val)])
    def ImageUpdateSlot(self, Image):
        self.QTcamera.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(Image))

class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def run(self):
        self.ThreadActive = True
        Capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self.ThreadActive:
            iSee = False
            controlXY = 0
            success, frame = Capture.read()
            if success:
                height, width = frame.shape[0:2]
                hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                binary = cv2.inRange(hsv, (0, 100, 250), (20, 255, 255))
                roi = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=binary)
                contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
                if len(contours) != 0:
                    maxcont = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
                    moments = cv2.moments(maxcont)
                    if moments["m00"] > 20:
                        cx = int(moments["m10"] / moments["m00"])
                        cy = int(moments["m01"] / moments["m00"])
                        iSee = True
                        controlXY = 100 * (cx - width / 2) / width
                        controlXY = controlXY * 1
                        cv2.drawContours(frame, maxcont, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        cv2.line(frame, (cx, 0), (cx, height), (0, 0, 255), 6)
                        cv2.line(frame, (0, cy), (width, cy), (0, 255, 0), 6)
                cv2.putText(frame, 'iSee: {};'.format(iSee), (width - 370, height - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4,
                            (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.putText(frame, 'controlX: {:.2f}'.format(controlXY), (width - 200, height - 10),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

                if iSee == True:
                    mainWindow.serialSend([2, controlXY]) # That's the most problematic function

            ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(frame.data, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_BGR888)
            Pic = ConvertToQtFormat.scaled(800, 600, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.ImageUpdate.emit(Pic)

def stop(self):
    self.ThreadActive = False
    self.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(f"Класс Worker имеет{Worker1.__dict__}")
    print(f"Класс CustomMainWindow имеет{CustomMainWindow.__dict__}")

    mainWindow = CustomMainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If there is no error message, use a debugger or add some `print`s to find out which code exactly is executed and which isn't.

Comment: From the [QSerialPort](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html) documentation: "The serial port is always opened with exclusive access (that is, no other process or thread can access an already opened serial port)." Which is exactly what you're doing. But, even if it were possible, *in any case* a thread should never try to access UI functions (and possibly, not even global variables). Create another signal for the worker, and emit it instead. Then do some research on proper usage of interthreading communication, including risks involved in accessing objects from different threads.

Comment: I also strongly suggest you to improve the way you do imports.